# android java permissions denial manifest.xml

Tags: java, android, permissions

Hi i am trying to build my  project but i am getting the folowing error

ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.my_app.app/.choose_language } from null (pid=-1, uid=-1) requires null

My manifest file is as following

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.my_app.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES" />


    <uses-sdk         
        android:targetSdkVersion="7" 
        android:minSdkVersion="7" 
 />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".Scan_AppActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".nearby_exhibits"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SegmentedRadioActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".ds_main_page"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".my_scan"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".help_menu"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".choose_language"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
                             <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".splash_screen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".register_screen"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".login"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".attraction_more_info"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="chosen_my_scan_attraction"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

if i remove the intent-filter part and add this to my splash screen activity my app starts fine but having this start up code on any other activity throws the above error.  Does anyne know why this is?

Answer (score 3):

Frequently, `requires null` in a `SecurityException` means that the component is not exported. That should not be a problem in your case -- an activity is automatically exported when it has an `<intent-filter>`. I would settle on which activity in your app will have the `<intent-filter>`, and do a full uninstall of the app from your device/emulator and then reinstall to see if this helps.

BTW, ordinary SDK applications cannot hold `ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES`.

Comment: Insightful answer @Commons. How did you manage to find info about the `requires null` relating to exported Activities? I'm trying to become a more knowledgeable Android developer but I would never have made such a connection if I hadn't read it from an answer like this on SO. Also, does this mean if an `Activity` doesn't include `intent-filters` then it can't be maliciously/surreptitiously called by a different Application?

Comment: @Turbo: "How did you manage to find info about the requires null relating to exported Activities?" -- IIRC, Dianne Hackborn mentioned it in an android-developers thread. "Also, does this mean if an Activity doesn't include intent-filters then it can't be maliciously/surreptitiously called by a different Application?" -- there is an `android:exported` property that controls whether third parties can invoke the activity. Having an `<intent-filter>` sets the default `android:exported` to `true`; otherwise, the default is `false`.

Comment: so as long as no intent filter is included, and the `android:exported` tag is not set to `true`, there should be no way for another application to launch another's activity?