# why do I need android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES

Tags: android, eclipse, permissions, android-manifest

I hope someone can help with this, I've been searching and have not found an explanation.

I written my application using Eclipse and tested in on the emulator and it works fine with no errors.  When I attempt to install the app on my phone, it fails complaining that the permission android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES is required.

```
[2014-01-21 09:02:44 - ShoppingCalc] Android Launch!
[2014-01-21 09:02:44 - ShoppingCalc] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-21 09:02:44 - ShoppingCalc] Performing com.jwg.shoppingcalc.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-01-21 09:02:48 - ShoppingCalc] Uploading ShoppingCalc.apk onto device '42f7aa046c719f73'
[2014-01-21 09:02:48 - ShoppingCalc] Installing ShoppingCalc.apk...
[2014-01-21 09:02:50 - ShoppingCalc] Success!
[2014-01-21 09:02:50 - ShoppingCalc] Starting activity com.jwg.shoppingcalc.MainActivity on device 42f7aa046c719f73
[2014-01-21 09:02:50 - ShoppingCalc] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.jwg.shoppingcalc/.MainActivity }
[2014-01-21 09:02:50 - ShoppingCalc] ActivityManager: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.jwg.shoppingcalc/.MainActivity } from null (pid=21219, uid=2000) requires android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES
[2014-01-21 09:02:50 - ShoppingCalc] ActivityManager: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
[2014-01-21 09:02:50 - ShoppingCalc] ActivityManager: at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
[2014-01-21 09:02:50 - ShoppingCalc] ActivityManager: at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:1930)
[2014-01-21 09:02:50 - ShoppingCalc] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.runStart(Am.java:463)
[2014-01-21 09:02:50 - ShoppingCalc] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.run(Am.java:108)
[2014-01-21 09:02:50 - ShoppingCalc] ActivityManager: at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:81)
[2014-01-21 09:02:50 - ShoppingCalc] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
[2014-01-21 09:02:50 - ShoppingCalc] ActivityManager: at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:237)
[2014-01-21 09:02:50 - ShoppingCalc] ActivityManager: at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[2014-01-21 09:04:57 - ShoppingCalc] Dx
```

On the emulator, installing the app looks like this.

```
[2014-01-21 09:33:48 - ShoppingCalc] Android Launch!
[2014-01-21 09:33:48 - ShoppingCalc] adb is running normally.
[2014-01-21 09:33:48 - ShoppingCalc] Performing com.jwg.shoppingcalc.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-01-21 09:33:52 - ShoppingCalc] Uploading ShoppingCalc.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2014-01-21 09:33:52 - ShoppingCalc] Installing ShoppingCalc.apk...
[2014-01-21 09:34:08 - ShoppingCalc] Success!
[2014-01-21 09:34:08 - ShoppingCalc] Starting activity com.jwg.shoppingcalc.MainActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-01-21 09:34:13 - ShoppingCalc] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.jwg.shoppingcalc/.MainActivity }
```

In my research I found that the permission android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES is for system apps only and cannot be granted even if included in the manifest.

The only change to the java code I made since it last worked on the phone was checking for a file on the device and if it does not exist, create the file.

Any detailed information about why an app would need this permission would be useful, what I found so far on line only states the minimum.

Thanks!

Adding manifest on 1/22/14

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.jwg.shoppingcalc.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>  
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.jwg.shoppingcalc.EnterTaxActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.jwg.shoppingcalc.EnterQuantity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
```

Comment: Please post the `<activity>` element from your manifest for this activity.

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627618/android-java-permissions-denial-manifest-xml

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for looking, I'm new at this and can use some help with this one.  here if the section from the manifest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks again, I was able to solve the problem.  It was in the manifest but on in the activity section.

In the application section there was a line added that I'm not sure how it got there as I did not add it, android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES"

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    android:persistent="false"
    android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES">
```

Commenting this line allowed the app to install and run again on the phone.

Comment: That's what I was expecting to see on an `<activity>`. I had forgotten that `android:permission` was also available on `<application>`. My apologies.